# Light controlled h-bridge?

Tags: h-bridge, opto-isolator

I was wondering if it would be smart to control a power H-bridge, with light. Imagine an opto-isolated power stage, where the opto-isolators are sawed in 2 parts connected by an optic fiber.

I think it would avoid close proximity of potentials we would like to avoid radiating into each other (and long electric cables). The idea sounds quite simple, but my googling didn't turn any ready made components (it might be a keyword problem), like finding an array of pin diodes with integrated optical connectors, or a complete readymade optical gate driver (laziness is good right?).

Comment: I believe this is occasionally done, when there's a very large voltage difference between the control logic and the transistors. Optical fiber won't be very cheap.

Comment: Just asking/curious:  How would this be different then say turning on the transistor bases/gates in a standard H bridge with an optoisolator chip?

Comment: mike> on the electrical functional level, this is exactly the same. But it's the electromagnetic side of things that is different, because the wires between the control unit and the power stage are either receiving (if the opto-isolator is physically with the power stage) or emitting antenas (if the opto-coupler is physically with the controller).

Answer (score 1):

In fact you'd need two optical fibers, to switch the bridge in one direction of in the another (typical h-bridge has two control inputs).

In such situation, I'd consider having a simple control unit (based on a microcontroller), and send it commands via a single optical fiber.

Comment: yes, I was thinking maybe 6 fibers, for a 3 phase motor control (hence the need for arrays of components, micro-connectors etc.)

Comment: But adding a micro-controller would defeat the whole purpose of having the micro-controller far from the EMC noise

Comment: So definitely, using of a control unit controlled by a single fiber should be much cheaper.
A nice website about using optoisolators to control h-bridge is here:
http://reddview.hubpages.com/hub/Optical-Isolation-and-Gate-Drive-Circuits-for-H-Bridge-Power-Electronics

Comment: You can still separate it from the h-bridge(s), using the transoptor(s) or another optoisolation (as mentioned in the previous comment)
However typical integrated h-bridges with digital inputs provide sufficient separation, to protect your microcontroller, and communication via optical fiber will eliminate ground loop problems.

Comment: I have found that link by googling, it's a very classical approach. As I said, those long cables between the control and power stages are still radiating or receiving, which I find a bit sad because in the system there is already a light system.

Answer (score 1):

A H bridge is powered by DC. Therefore emissions from AC can be largely discounted. Because of the DC nature of H bridge circuits, controlling them directly, with digital signals isn't really a brain ache. Even if the DC supply is hundreds of volts it isn't really hard to use opto isolators or transformers or capacitive coupling devices.

The question sounds like an idea searching for an application and I can think of none.

Even if such devices as cyclo converters were considered, I don't see an engineering problem that cannot be solved by using the tried and tested methods. BTW. Cyclo converters switch the AC power directly to produce different power AC frequencies for driving induction motors at variable speeds.

Can it be done without optical fibres? Yes. Are they effective? Yes. Are they reliable? Yes if the power transistors are sufficiently rated.

Where does technology like this fail? In the power transistors, the power diodes and any other silicon closely associated with the output stage.

Answer (score 1):

You're describing something that sounds a hell of a lot like a high-voltage onto-isolator. They're basically a LED and a phototransistor coupled to a long light-pipe.

[image]

The reason this isn't a more known practice is because there is no point. It's cheaper and easier to just shield a local MCU then it is to deal with exotic optical components. You're solving one problem by introducing far more complexity.

I also think you're grossly overestimating the size of the issue EMC-resistant design actually is. Pickup in wires is much more easily dealt with by just using differential signaling. Electromagnetic interference is more easily dealt with by just putting the relevant PCBA in a box. Magnetic interference is a rare issue, and you can compensate with things like Mu-metal.

The one area where something like you describe could be useful is ultra-high-strength magnetic field environments (like MRIs), and even there, it's often much easier to just deal with the induced noise with careful filtering.

Exotic opto-isolators like the one pictured above are only around because you actually *need* that much isolation space for really, **really** high voltages (the one above is rated for 50 KV!).